# Making an area un-editable using a checkbox

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word, office365

I have a word-document and want to make a specific area uneditable (greyed out) if the value of a `checkbox` is `true`. My problem is that there are some errors, which I am unable to fix it by myself, hopefully you can help me out with it.

```
Sub checkBoxStatus()

'declare variables
Dim cb3Y As CheckBox
Dim cb3N As CheckBox

Set cb3Y = ActiveDocument.FormFields(1).CheckBox

cb3Y.Value = False 'just needed this for debugging, to see if I got the right checkbox

End Sub
```

I got an error message all the time when running this code fragment. "Runtime Error '5941' The Requested Member of Collection Does Not Exist". Unfortunately I don't know where I can edit the id of the right checkbox I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no CheckBox collection. Use something like:

```
Sub checkBoxStatus()
With ActiveDocument
  If .FormFields(1).CheckBox.Value = True Then
    ' code for true here
  Else
    ' code for false here
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have 2 `checkBoxes` in my current word document. How can I disable one if the other is selected?
I tried this:
`Dim cb1 As Checkbox
Dim cb2 As CheckBox

cb1 = FormFields(1).Checkbox

'here the other code`

That doesn't work. I just want to declare my checkbox (named cb1) as a variable to do a lot of stuff with it

Comment: Did you even bother to read the answer I posted??? As I said «There is *no* CheckBox collection». There are plenty of examples online for making formfield checkboxes exclusive.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I didn't understand you right there. Was not clear for me what you meant by <<no CheckBox collection>>. Whatever, your answers solves my issue. Thanks a lot